# Property of nonconvex polygons

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, polygons

How to prove that each non-convex polygon with no self-intersecting parts, has at least one interior angle which size is less then $180$ degrees.

Comment: In case of self-intersecting polygons, what is your definition of "interior angle"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Consider the vertex with the largest $x$-coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the sum of the angles of a polygon, as a function of the number of sides, holds for non-convex as well as for convex polygons, and the result follows immediately from that formula.

Comment: Can you please share proof of that formula for non-convex polygons

Comment: Why not first look at the proof for convex polygons, and see whether it works?

Comment: There the polygon is divided into triangles, which is not trivial for non-convex polygons, in fact I need to prove it using this affirmation

Comment: That's one way. Another is by considering "exterior angles".